# Community string indexing error in non-cisco switches

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, network-management

I am trying to retrieve CAM table information from non-cisco switches. I am using **D-Link DES 3526** and **Brocade fastiron sx 800** switches and installed net-snmp. When I execute the cmd:    $snmpwalk -v 2c -c public@[vlanid] [ip-address] 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1
I am getting **TIMEOUT error**. I googled for the answer and found that **[comm]@[vlanid] is cisco specific**. Visit ftp://ftp.cisco.com/pub/mibs/supportlists/wsc1200/wsc1200-communityIndexing.html. So can anyone say how to do community string indexing for non-cisco switches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So can anyone say how to do community string indexing for non-cisco switches?

This is how to poll Q-BRIDGE-MIB for mac-addresses from the only non-Cisco I have, a DLink DGS-3200.  I'm *not* using [community@vlan] for non-Cisco switches.  Indexing BRIDGE-MIB with [community@vlan] only applies to Ciscos.

I expect any non-Cisco switch, which supports Q-BRIDGE-MIB to work the following way.

#### Polling [sysDescr](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=sysDescr&translate=Translate) to document the switch under test

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ # Demo from a DLink DGS-3200 switch
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public -OXsq 172.16.1.2 sysdescr
sysDescr.0 "DGS-3200-10 Gigabit Ethernet Switch"
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

#### Walking [dot1qVlanStaticName](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1qVlanStaticName&translate=Translate): List Vlans and their text names

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public 172.16.1.2 
 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.4.3.1.1
BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dBridge.7.1.4.3.1.1.1 = STRING: "default"
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

#### [dot1qFdbDynamicCount](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1qFdbDynamicCount&translate=Translate): Number of mac addresses known

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ 
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public  172.16.1.2 
 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.1.1.2
BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dBridge.7.1.2.1.1.2.1 = Counter32: 17
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

#### [dot1qVlanCurrentEgressPorts](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1qVlanCurrentEgressPorts&translate=Translate): bitmap of ports in the vlan

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ 
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public 172.16.1.2 
 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.4.2.1.4
BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dBridge.7.1.4.2.1.4.2562.1 = Hex-STRING: FF C0 00 00
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

#### [dot1qTpFdbPort](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=dot1qTpFdbPort&translate=Translate): All MAC Addresses learned

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ 
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public 172.16.1.2 
 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2
BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dBridge.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.0.13.101.22.120.35 = INTEGER: 5
BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dBridge.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.0.13.189.12.143.198 = INTEGER: 5
BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dBridge.7.1.2.2.1.2.1.0.13.189.7.34.145 = INTEGER: 5

... more entries here
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

Comment: Using Q-bridge I am able to retrieve only the port number using the oid you mentioned above but my focus is on retrieving all mac address (under all Vlan). But Q-bridge dot1qTpFdbAddress **1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.1** permission is set to **not-accessible**. Is there a way to retrive it?